How to force call non-the best match method if multiple methods matched in java
I knew that java will call the best match method if there are multiple methods matched. Refer to the code below, is it possible to force call non-the best match method without modifying method signature ?
public static class Example<T> {

    public static <T> Example<T> example(T data) {
        return null;
    }

    public static <T> Example<T> example(String msg) {
        return null;
    }

    public static <T> Example<T> example(String... args) {
        return null;
    }

    public static void example() {
        Example<?> msgExample = example("msg");

        // how to call `result(T data)` instead `result(String msg)` ?
        Example<String> dataExample = example("data");
        // working but required double casting
        Example<String> dataExampleByCasting = (Example<String>) ((Example<?>) example((Object) "data"));

        // how to call `result(String... args)` instead `result(String msg)` ?
        Example<?> argsExample = example("args");
        // working but required new array
        Example<?> argsExampleByNewArray = example(new String[]{"args"});
    }

}

UPDATE
I try to rephrase explain my question, and the fields in Example are omitted.
These methods have different semantics:

example(T data): data means data needs to be returned, but the values ​​of fields such as status and information are fixed, such as request succeed

example(String msg): msg means error message, and no data needs to be returned at this time, such as request failed

example(String... args): args is extended based on the above two cases for additional processing


Now, if data is of type String, example(T data) cannot be called because of the best match rule, it is similar for while the args has only one parameter.

What exactly is the need being addressed here?  Trying to change the behavior of the language to fit one's code, instead of the other way around, is probably the wrong approach...

What is the context? I cannot imagine why you should need to call example(String... args) with only one string.

This is on compilation level. Compilation failing or choosing wrong type - use direct template specification Foo.example<String>("Hello world!")

Creating a new array isn't an issue, varargs is just a convenience for doing that.

The alternative methods need to be explicitly specified using the syntax you already show in your example calls. That's not an issue. What is an issue is that if you have a situation that requires selecting the non-best method, then perhaps you haven't defined your method overloads to behave in an intuitive way. If they were, then the best-matched method should be the exact one you'd want to call.

@David I updated the question and explained why I did this.

@CardinalSystem I updated the question and explained why I did this.

The update makes it sound like you have 3 poorly named methods. 1 Processing data 2 Posting an error message 3. Some amalgam of the two. Why do you have the single String version of the method? Having a generic method overloading a specific object method is bound to cause some errors.

@VictorGubin did you try what you're suggesting? The syntax you show breaks for me, the only way I get it to compile is to Foo.<String>example("string"); then it still defaults to the String method.

@matt You mean, in this case, I should not overload the method, but use a more semantically clear method name, such as: success(T data), failure(String msg).

You can't call the 'worst matching' method.
The only way you can achieve your desired outcome, is the one you already described at the end of your code, so yes, you need to create a new array for the method call.
To generalize the solution: You need to adjust the parameter-types you provide when you call a method. This might require creating a new array and sometimes it will be enough to cast your object to another one.
